# GHCJS: How to use a JS library that is intended to be used with npm

Tags: reactjs, haskell, npm, material-design, ghcjs

I'm using `ghcjs-0.2.0.9006030_ghc-7.10.3` with stack `lts-6.30` to build a frontend app. Inspired by [this post](http://blog.wuzzeb.org/full-stack-web-haskell/client.html), I decided to use `react-flux` and `material-ui`. I added React's CDN link to my index.html, and [configured](https://gist.github.com/fizruk/fb5bad8a08a4b788764851c11ebbadf8) GHCJSi to use a custom `index-dev.html` when working with the repl.(React's CDN link is also included in `index-dev.html`)

However, with [material-ui-next](https://material-ui-next.com/), the [official installation method](https://material-ui-next.com/getting-started/installation/) is to use NPM. They provide no CDN link. So how to use this library in a GHCJS project? I think one of the following should work:

- Use the [CDN link](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/material-ui-next@1.0.0-beta.34/index.js) provided by jsDelivr. (Though this link doesn't work)
- Find some way to bundle `material-ui-next` and put it in `js-sources` field in cabal, so that it can be linked with our app at build time.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [package.json](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/6fe39e056d1202db59eb41e16e6777f862ac9d85/package.json) of material-ui, scripts `build:umd:prod` and `build:umd:dev` can be used to build UMD bundles of the package. So you can use the [CDN link](https://unpkg.com/material-ui@1.0.0-beta.35/umd/material-ui.development.js) provided by [unpkg](https://unpkg.com).

Even though `material-ui` doesn't declare a peer dependency on `react-transition-group`, it expects `react-transition-group/TransitionGroup` to be present. So we have to add the following code **before** the link to `material-ui`

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/react-transition-group@2.2.1/dist/react-transition-group.js"></script>
<script>
    window["react-transition-group/TransitionGroup"] = ReactTransitionGroup.TransitionGroup;
</script>
```

I created a issue on `material-ui`'s github repository, see [that issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10507) for more details.